# MySql - Add comma delimiter

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-workbench

Is there a way for adding commas for values for IN clause? e.g. if my query

```
 SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Id IN(.....)
```

and I've copied from csv file, example:

```
12
23
58
55
```

I tried to put the cursor on the left of 12 and hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>,  click the down key for as many numbers as you have, I saw the line and I released the keys (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>) I pressed comma (`,`) but it's applied on just one line, what I did wrong?

Comment: Editing features are not universal. What's your editor?

Comment: There's only 4 numbers there why not just type them?

Comment: Since you are using **csv** file, open your file in notepad and copy from there. It will have commas

Comment: @P.Salmon no I have a list of 1700 it s not obvious to do it manually ,

Comment: I m using ubuntu , I m asking if there s a way or a trick to separate elements of a list with comma in mysql

Comment: At 1700 entries you may be pushing it performance wise using an in statement why not load them into a table and use a join instead

Comment: Ubuntu is not a text editor. Whatever happens when you hit a bunch of keys mostly depends on the program you're using, not the operating system. I insist: what editor are you typing this on?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález , yes absolutely ubuntu isn't an editor , I m using MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Google Chrome/FireFox and development tool enabled (Press F12 to show it)?
You can go to console and paste this code

```
let lines = `
Paste text from csv here
`;
let lineText = lines.split('\n').filter(x => x.trim().length > 0).map(x => x.trim())
console.log(` SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Id IN(${lineText.join(', ')})`)
```

Then you can paste the text copied from csv to `Paster text from csv here`

Then enter. You will get the sql script in the console. Then copy the sql and paste to mysql command executor.

[image: Like this image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> adds several cursors in MySQL Workbench but (for whatever the reason) they don't behave as such. The editor, however, supports regular expressions to search and replace so you can use that:

1. Select all lines but the last one.
2. Go to *Edit/ Find/ Find and Replace* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>).
3. Set the *Regular Expression* mode from the tiny  icon:

   [image: Regular Expression]
4. Search for `$` (end of line) and replace with `,` (comma).
5. Hit *Replace All*.

   [image: Replace All]

Disclaimer: my copy of Workbench for Windows freezes everytime I try. If yours does too, you may want to just switch to another MySQL client; this regexp syntax is pretty much universal across editors.